# HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error in enterprise java beans deployment

Tags: java, httpexception, servletexception

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error when trying to deploy a web application using enterprise java beans in `netbeans` running `glassfish` server

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

**Type:** Exception report

**Message:** Internal Server Error

**Description:** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**Exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.registaration.registrationcontroller
root cause

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class com.registaration.registrationcontroller
root cause

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.registaration.registrationcontroller/registrationservice,Remote 3.x interface =com.registration.registrationserviceRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.registration.registrationserviceRemote,refType=Session into class com.registaration.registrationcontroller: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.registaration.registrationcontroller/registrationservice' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.registaration.registrationcontroller/registrationservice' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.registaration.registrationcontroller/registrationservice,Remote 3.x interface =com.registration.registrationserviceRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.registration.registrationserviceRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.registration.registrationserviceRemote#com.registration.registrationserviceRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.registration.registrationserviceRemote#com.registration.registrationserviceRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.registration.registrationserviceRemote#com.registration.registrationserviceRemote not found]]]
root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.registaration.registrationcontroller/registrationservice,Remote 3.x interface =com.registration.registrationserviceRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.registration.registrationserviceRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.registration.registrationserviceRemote#com.registration.registrationserviceRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.registration.registrationserviceRemote#com.registration.registrationserviceRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.registration.registrationserviceRemote#com.registration.registrationserviceRemote not found]]
root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.registration.registrationserviceRemote#com.registration.registrationserviceRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.registration.registrationserviceRemote#com.registration.registrationserviceRemote not found]
root cause

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.registration.registrationserviceRemote#com.registration.registrationserviceRemote not found
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.
```

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1

Comment: Post your error stack trace.

Comment: i have editted the question showing what apper when i run the application

Comment: have a look the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.